# How to detect if function is implemented in installed library?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, linker

I have my program for windows, which uses windows system library (let's name it `"sysLib"`), and it implements function `"libFun1"`. My program can look like this:

```cpp
#include <sysLib.h>

void myFunction() {
    //some magic here
}

int main() {
    myFunction();
    libFun1();
    return 0;
}
```

later, library gets update, in which new `"libFun2"` function is added and it perfectly does what my `"myFunction"` do and even does it better. So I update my program to look like this:

```cpp
#include <sysLib.h>

int main() {
    libFun2();
    libFun1();
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it and push update to clients.
But there are some clients, who doesn't have last version of windows and they have the old version of `"sysLib"` which doesn't implement `"libFun2"`, so program for them doesn't work (doesn't even start).
I figured out, that if i compile my program with `"delayimp.lib /DELAYLOAD:sysLib.dll"`, program is now startable, but falls when `"libFun2"` is called.
I would like to now update my code to looku something like this:

```cpp
#include <sysLib.h>

void myFunction() {
    //some magic here
}

int main() {
    if(/*libFun2 exists*/) {
         libFun2();
    } else {
         myFunction();
    }
    libFun1();
    return 0;
}
```

How can i detect, if `"libFun2"` function exists inside library and make logic around it?

> I know that in linux is possible to do `if(libFun2)`, but this doesn't work in windows

### UPDATE:

I found out, that it can be catched by __try __except combination, but it doesnt work for me...

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/error-handling-and-notification?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is pretty simple:

```cpp
#include <sysLib.h>
#include <delayimp.h>
int CheckDelayException(int exception_value)
{
    if (exception_value == VcppException(ERROR_SEVERITY_ERROR, ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND) ||
        exception_value == VcppException(ERROR_SEVERITY_ERROR, ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND))
    {
        // This example just executes the handler.
        return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
    }
    // Don't attempt to handle other errors
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

void myFunction() {
    __try {
         libFun2();
         return;
    } __except (CheckDelayException(GetExceptionCode())) {
         myFunction();
    }
    //some magic here
}

int main() {
    myFunction();
    libFun1();
    return 0;
}
```

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/error-handling-and-notification?view=msvc-170

> **UPDATE:** moved __try into function for better usage in code, if multiple calls are used

Comment: But this is really bad if you will call it more than once.  Better to use a function pointer that you update in the `__except` block so that the next call goes straight to the local implementation and doesn't try to call the missing import again

Answer (score 5):

```
bool hasExport(LPCSTR mod, LPCSTR func)
{
  HMODULE handle = LoadLibraryA(mod);
  return handle && GetProcAddress(handle, func);
}

...

if (hasExport("syslib", "libfun2"))
  libfun2(); // must be delay loaded
else
  ...
```

This code assumes that you don't need to unload the library again. It also does not care if the library was already loaded. Use `GetModuleHandle` or `FreeLibrary` if you need a different behavior.

In this specific case, since you have a replacement function you could instead use a delayload hook and handle `dliFailGetProc` by returning the fallback function.

Comment: this solution isn't clear by my point of view. Its based on fact that you write name of funtion correctly, and when library is written in combination of c and c++, the names of function aren't so clear... I found out that exception of GetProcAddress can be caught, but im strugling to do so... (viz. update)

Comment: This is the only answer that correctly answers the _asked_ question, and it works with all compilers, not just MSVC.

Comment: @ottosleger `GetProcAddress` does not throw exceptions.

Comment: @Anders: Not for ordinary failure to find the exported function, anyway.  If you use it wrong it will (OS structured exceptions, that is, not C++ exceptions)

Comment: @BenVoigt Well yes, if you pass it an invalid module or string address it might but that basically applies to every function that has a parameter that points to something.

Comment: @Anders Code I use in my answer works...